# Is there a good app that lets me to the app updates in one go?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

Right now in the market you have to manually update each app, is there an app that automates this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Users can update several apps at once using Android version 2.2.
An [answer](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=6e1fc7a2d5e86c51&hl=enhigher) in the Android support forum says:

> They have added this already but this
>   is probably limited to market client
>   app on Android 2.2 aka FroYo and
>   higher firmware.

Also, I don't see anything in the market would bring this out for pre-2.2 phones, but it could be out there.

Answer (score 13):

I use [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps) it automates the install procedure a bit.

Comment: But you still can't update all at once without 2.2, right? ;)

Comment: No, the AppBrain app works just fine with older versions. It merely goes through each app in turn. You do have to press buttons at each step, but it will at least go through each one without you having to go back to the market each time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after apps that automatically update themselves when an update is available, as of Android 2.2 there is an option to mark an app to automatically update. Then you'll never be bothered by an update alert for that app again (unless the security profile changes).

Comment: The only catch to this is that if you are rooted, you may experience difficulties with automatic or manual updating from time to time, especially with system applications. I suppose that does apply to any version though.

Answer (score 0):

On 2.2 (all I have access to) use the Marketplace app, 
open the menu, select My Apps. 
All your installed apps will be shown, any with available updates will be shown at the top.

I don't see a way to then Actually update all that have available updates though. 
And apparently on older versions this feature is not available as a part of the marketplace.

Comment: At the bottom of the screen will be a button that says "Update All".

Comment: I don't see it on 2.2.

Comment: If you've got the newly redesigned Market app (with the curved green area at the top) the Update All button is now at the top of the My Apps screen, if you've got pending updates to be installed.