# how to batch update one's market application?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good app that lets me to the app updates in one go?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1600/is-there-a-good-app-that-lets-me-to-the-app-updates-in-one-go)

can I batch update the apps I dowloaded from the market? I receive notifications like "14 updates available", but I don't know how to update them all, usually I just click some important apps and update manually. It's tiring and takes quite some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been asked and answered: [Is there a good app that lets me to the app updates in one go?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1600)